# Moderncv does not create PDF

Tags: compiling, moderncv

I have written my CV's with a template i made in 2013 and it has worked since then.
Now since I reinstalled Windows 7 and everything some months ago i can't compile those CV's anymore.
I can compile other documents such as `scrartcl` or `scrrprt`.
with trial and error I found out that the problems are the lines

```
\makecvtitle
```

and

```
\section{Hobbies}
    \cvlistitem{Watching the Grass grow}
```

When one of these two is included, it won't produce a PDF. It will produce the file `CV.synctex.(busy)`. But it is not actually busy - there is no process in the task manager and I can delete this file. There is no error notification, but there is the followeing warning, which as I remember I always had and it still produced a proper PDF:

```
 You have requested package `moderncvheadi',but the package provides `moderncvheadi'.
```

I am using `Texmaker 5.0.2`, `MikTeX 2.9` and `moderncv 2.0.0`.

In the settings of Texmaker I have in the field for pdflatex (which was there by default):

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Thanks a hell lot for telling me what I need to change about installation or settings or whatever so I can compile my CV without changing to another class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Smith}
\address{Avocado Avenue}{1234 Longyearbyen}
\mobile{+99 (0)12 345 67 89}
\email{john.smith@gmail.com}

\title{CV}

\begin{document}
%\makecvtitle    %This line causes the compiler to fail

\section{Personal Data}
    \cvitem{Date of birth}{1st January 1980}

\section{Experience}
    \cventry{1998 -- 2005}{Researcher}{Umbrealla Corporation}{Longyearbyen}{}{Researching Stuff}

\section{Hobbies}
%   \cvlistitem{Watching the Grass grow}    %This line causes the compiler to fail

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wanted to add log file but i has 60'000 lines...

Comment: Your MWE compiles fine for me and the log is "only" 1354 lines long. Can you make your log file available somewhere else? For example https://pastebin.com/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LeYFd2y3

Comment: It only fails if the percents are removed before the `\makecvtitle` and `\cvlistitem`. Perhaps these commands are outdated? But there is no documentation on CTAN, only examples that use these commands.

Comment: Not sure how to fix it, but the problem seems to be `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file umvs): Font umvs at 657 not found`

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183081/struggling-to-get-moderncv-files-to-compile

Answer (score 0):

I could compile the file.
The solution was to open the command prompt and enter `updmap`.
I have absolutely no idea what that does and why it worked...

Thank to @samcarter for posting this link:

[Struggling to get moderncv files to compile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183081/struggling-to-get-moderncv-files-to-compile)