# The same tex file working in old version is not running in latest version

Tags: errors, pdftex, installing, texstudio, versions

A very old version of LaTeX was installed in my computer. Recently, I removed that old version and have installed the latest TeXstudio 2.12.8. But the files which were running in the old version without showing any warning, now is not running in the latest version. I gave run a file several times. It shows the following error

[image]

#### EDIT: log file from running  `moderncv` tex file

[image]

Comment: that message is saying that pdflatex is not properly installed, not that there is a problem with that document. Do other documents work?

Comment: You say you installed texstudio but that is just an editor, have you also installed tex (miktex or texlive)??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no, I haven't installed miktex or texlive. Which one should I install? Is there any preference one over the other?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have installed miktex.  Now every documents work except the `moderncv` document. When I run the tex copy of my cv, it shows the error in my post.

Comment: was that instance of texstudio already running when you sinstalled miktex? it isnt finding pdftex, try just quitting and restarting, sorry i can't help more I do not have miktex or texstudio

Comment: Are there any updates here? Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: @Troy Yes, I am still facing the problem. My every document is working smoothly except the `moderncv` tex file. Previously the same file ran without any warning. But now, it shows the error massage that I have shown in my original post.

Comment: does running xelatex or lualatex work? canyou show the log file?

Comment: @Troy I have edited my original post to show the log file produced from running the `moderncv` tex file. The log file shows I have undefined citation. But  previously the same file was running without any warning. This document is nothing but the file of this link https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-classic

Comment: The `moderncv` warning is a known bug of that class/template. Undefined citations mean, that you probably didn't run the extra step to build the bibliography/citations. -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

Comment: @user149054 Warnings and errors are different; you can ignore the former. That’s not the log file by the way: In your build folder (where your .tex file is located), a .log file should be produced. Paste its contents here. Just to confirm: you are still receiving the “memory dump” *error* when compiling the main.tex file from the moderncv template? because the second img you posted suggests to me the build went fine.

Comment: @Troy That log file size is 55.8kb. Too big to paste the contents of the log file here.

Comment: @user149054 Ok, use pastebin then. Still receiving the memory dump problem, or no?

Comment: @Troy It is really great to make me familiar with `pastebin`. Thank you so much. Here is the link https://pastebin.com/Va67h1A0. When I run the moderncv tex file, it doesn't produce any pdf.

Comment: @user149054 Well, the log file says `umvs.fd` not found, (see 2nd last line of log file), which is one of the fonts moderncv uses. (1) Do you have `marvosym` package installed? (Check using the MikTeX console `->` Packages). (2) Run `Refresh File Name Database` and `Refresh font map files` via MikTeX console `->` Tasks, on *both* admin and user mode. (3) Follow the solution here (i.e., run `updmap` on Windows cmd prompt) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307736/117534. (4) This qn has the same symptoms as you: try the other solutions if the above doesnt work.

Comment: @Troy Thank you sooooooooo much. It is now working. I had lost the hope of making my CV in LaTeX. Thank you again.

Comment: @user149054 No problem, glad I could help. I will vote to close this question as duplicate, if that is alright with you.

Comment: @Troy It's alright. But only running the `Refresh File Name Database` and `Refresh font map files` via MikTeX console -> Tasks, on both admin and user mode and running  `updmap` on Windows cmd prompt solve the problem. I didn't need to do anything else.